# The pagination `before` and `complete` options not working properly

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to display a loading image when I click on a sorting link of a listing record. Before, I used the `complete` property of `Paginator`. This works well if the table has more than one record.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#ourCompany-part',
    'evalScripts' => true,
    'before' => $this->Js->get('#loading')->
                           effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
    'complete' => $this->Js->get('#loading')->
                           effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
    ));
?>
```

When the table has one record and we click on the sorting link of the paginator, it doesn't display the loading image. If the table has no records, then the index page is not loaded. How could I solve this?

Comment: Are you using `$this->Paginator->sort(..)` to display the sort link?

Comment: It obvious, but you do have a javascript library of some sort loaded right?

Comment: You need to code to check to see if there are any records. Obviously if there is only one page worth, it wont give you navigation buttons - you will need to account for this too.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i don't like JsHelper i wrote jquery pugins or small function in my view. So check that the javascript looks like where you see 1 record or no record, it seems that helper not render javascitpt.